# Codeigniter User Agent Not Working On Logout Controller

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In my MY_Controller.php I have a redirect in there if session has expired.

Then it redirects to the logout controller. I have added a if statement `agent->is_referral` to the logout controller and set flashdata. Because it has been redirect from dashboard controller it should pick up that if statement and set flashdata but does not.

> **Question:** If the customer is redirected from whatever controller to logout then how to get `is_referral()` to detect and set the flashdata message. flashdata message is not setting when inside `is_referral()` if statement.

controllers > account > Logout.php

```
<?php

class Logout extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->library('user_agent');

        if ($this->agent->is_referral()) {
            // Does not set the flashdata if redirected from another controller.
            $this->session->set_flashdata('warning', 'Your session has expired!');  
        }

        // Flashdata works if have it here.
        // $this->session->set_flashdata('warning', 'Your session has expired!');

        $this->customer->logout();

        redirect('/'); // redirect to login page.
    }
}
```

core > MY_Controller.php

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        if ($this->uri->segment(1)) {

            if (!$this->session->userdata('customer_id')) {

                $route = $this->uri->segment(1) .'/'. $this->uri->segment(2);

                if (isset($route)) {

                    $ignore = array(
                        'account/logout'
                    );

                    if (!in_array($route, $ignore)) {
                        redirect('account/logout');
                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

controllers > account > Dashboard.php

```
<?php

class Dashboard extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('common/header_view');
        $this->load->view('account/dashboard_view');
        $this->load->view('common/footer_view');
    }
}
```

Comment: In dashboard set_flashdata in logout keep_flashdata in third place check or reed flashdata.

Comment: @Tpojka it seems to work with `$this->agent->referrer()` instead of `$this->agent->is_referral()`

Comment: There you go. Just don't rely much on user agent data since it can be easily overridden. Anything from user browser is not something security should depends on. You should use sessions.

Comment: @Tpojka What would you recommend since you said don't rely on user agent?

Comment: If you wan't to know something like last page, use `uri_string()`.